# A way to convert a from a hexadecimal string?

Tags: perl

I am parsing an html documents, and there is a variable `var key = 0xa9` for example, i do use my regex and all, but the `0xa9` i am getting is stored in a variable as a string, is there any cast function or anything to convert it to a number?

**EDIT** :

I am sure i didn't explain myself well, this is what i have been trying to do :

`$t = $t . chr ( ord(substr($e, $i, 1)) ^ $var);` BUT `$var = "0xa9"` or whatever, the thing is it is a string, so in the previous operation i do get an error `Argument "0xc2" isn't numeric in bitwise xor (^) at`, that is why i want the exact same value but not as a string, in order to work, $var needs to be like `$var = 0xa9` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
print hex '0xAf'; # prints '175'
```

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html)

```
hex
Interprets EXPR as a hex string and returns the corresponding value. 
(To convert strings that might start with either 0 , 0x , or 0b, see oct.) 
If EXPR is omitted, uses $_ .
```

Comment: I want to get `0xAf` to use it in an `xor` operation :/, but i do get it as a string instead.

Comment: If I understood correctly your comment, you should try to add with zero the result `hex('0xAf')+0` to have a numeric result

Comment: it worked finally, i have long script and i didn't notice one little mistake, thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

`print hex $string`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `0x0` to `$var`. It should convert the second operand in XOR operation to numeric value.

```
$t = $t . chr ( ord(substr($e, $i, 1)) ^ ($var + 0x0));
```

Comment: no it doesn't work, it just needs hex($var) as everyone suggested ^^;